# Optimize MySQL aggregate rank and leaderboards queries based on total score, max score and global, country, province

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, rank

I've encountered a rather complex and difficult problem with ranking and leaderboards in MySQL.

First of all, here is the `game_instances` table structure (striped):

```
+----+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | country                   | region | score | moves | finished_at         |
+----+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |   404 |    71 | 2021-05-14 02:56:10 |
|  2 |       1 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |   686 |   138 | 2021-05-14 02:58:13 |
|  3 |       1 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |  NULL |  NULL | NULL                |
|  4 |       2 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Yazd   |  1162 |   194 | 2021-05-14 03:03:00 |
|  5 |       2 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Yazd   |   220 |    56 | 2021-05-14 03:04:19 |
|  6 |       2 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Yazd   |     8 |     5 | 2021-05-14 03:05:13 |
|  7 |       2 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |   280 |    70 | 2021-05-14 03:06:11 |
|  8 |       2 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |  NULL |  NULL | NULL                |
|  9 |       3 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |   570 |   107 | 2021-05-14 03:10:26 |
| 10 |       3 | Iran, Islamic Republic Of | Qom    |     0 |     0 | 2021-05-14 03:32:40 |
+----+---------+---------------------------+--------+-------+-------+---------------------+
```

I need the rank number for a specific user by:

- Total Score: Global
- Total Score: Country
- Total Score: Region
- High Score: Global
- High Score: Country
- High Score: Region

And also leaderboards of these 6 segments for the top 10 users. That leaves for 12 data sets in total.

I've searched and tried many hours in the StackOverflow and other sites with no success. Currently, I'm fetching this data with 12 separate queries, which is not a good practice at all, I'm looking for a way to combine and optimize these queries as much as possible.

**EDIT:** I'm using **MySQL 5.7**.

Here is my current implementation:

```
public function leaderboard(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->input('_user');
    if (!$user) {
        return apiSend(null, 401);
    }

    $data = [
        'total' => [
            'player' => [
                'score' => 0,
                'global_rank' => 0,
                'country_rank' => 0,
                'region_rank' => 0,
            ],
            'global' => [], 'country' => [], 'region' => [],
        ],
        'high' => [
            'player' => [
                'score' => 0,
                'global_rank' => 0,
                'country_rank' => 0,
                'region_rank' => 0,
            ],
            'global' => [], 'country' => [], 'region' => [],
        ],
    ];

    $countryWhereClause = $user->country ? "WHERE country = '{$user->country}'" : 'WHERE country IS NULL';
    $regionWhereClause = $user->region ? "AND region = '{$user->region}'" : 'AND region IS NULL';

    $totalGlobalRank = DB::select("SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = {$user->id}");
    $totalCountryRank = DB::select("SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances {$countryWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = {$user->id}");
    $totalRegionRank = DB::select("SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances {$countryWhereClause} {$regionWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = {$user->id}");
    $highGlobalRank = DB::select("SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = {$user->id}");
    $highCountryRank = DB::select("SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances {$countryWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = {$user->id}");
    $highRegionRank = DB::select("SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances {$countryWhereClause} {$regionWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = {$user->id}");
    if (count($totalGlobalRank)) {
        $data['total']['player']['score'] = $totalGlobalRank[0]->total_score;
        $data['total']['player']['global_rank'] = $totalGlobalRank[0]->rank;
    }
    if (count($totalCountryRank)) {
        $data['total']['player']['country_rank'] = $totalCountryRank[0]->rank;
    }
    if (count($totalRegionRank)) {
        $data['total']['player']['region_rank'] = $totalRegionRank[0]->rank;
    }

    if (count($highGlobalRank)) {
        $data['high']['player']['score'] = $highGlobalRank[0]->max_score;
        $data['high']['player']['global_rank'] = $highGlobalRank[0]->rank;
    }
    if (count($highCountryRank)) {
        $data['high']['player']['country_rank'] = $highCountryRank[0]->rank;
    }
    if (count($highRegionRank)) {
        $data['high']['player']['region_rank'] = $highRegionRank[0]->rank;
    }

    $countryWhereClause = $user->country ? "WHERE g.country = '{$user->country}'" : 'WHERE g.country IS NULL';
    $regionWhereClause = $user->region ? "AND g.region = '{$user->region}'" : 'AND g.region IS NULL';

    $totalGlobalLeaderboards = $this->totalGlobalLeaderboards($user);
    $totalCountryLeaderboards = $this->totalCountryLeaderboards($user);
    $totalRegionLeaderboards = $this->totalRegionLeaderboards($user);
    $highGlobalLeaderboards = $this->highGlobalLeaderboards($user);
    $highCountryLeaderboards = $this->highCountryLeaderboards($user);
    $highRegionLeaderboards = $this->highRegionLeaderboards($user);
    foreach ($totalGlobalLeaderboards as $r) {
        $data['total']['global'][] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => $r->total_score, 'rank' => $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }
    foreach ($totalCountryLeaderboards as $r) {
        $data['total']['country'][] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => (int) $r->total_score, 'rank' => $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }
    foreach ($totalRegionLeaderboards as $r) {
        $data['total']['region'][] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => (int) $r->total_score, 'rank' => $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }
    foreach ($highGlobalLeaderboards as $r) {
        $data['high']['global'][] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => (int) $r->max_score, 'rank' => $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }
    foreach ($highCountryLeaderboards as $r) {
        $data['high']['country'][] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => (int) $r->max_score, 'rank' => $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }
    foreach ($highRegionLeaderboards as $r) {
        $data['high']['region'][] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => (int) $r->max_score, 'rank' => $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }

    return apiSend($data);
}

// Returns leaderboards with ranks near user rank, if user is not in the top 10.
public function userLeaderboards(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->input('_user');
    if (!$user) {
        return apiSend(null, 401);
    }

    $rank = (int) $request->query('rank');
    $type = $request->query('type');
    $scope = $request->query('scope');

    if ($rank <= 10) {
        return apiSend(null, 400);
    }

    $data = [];
    $rows = [];
    switch (true) {
        case $type == 'total' && $scope == 'global':
            $rows = $this->totalGlobalLeaderboards($user, $rank);
            break;
        case $type == 'total' && $scope == 'country':
            $rows = $this->totalCountryLeaderboards($user, $rank);
            break;
        case $type == 'total' && $scope == 'region':
            $rows = $this->totalRegionLeaderboards($user, $rank);
            break;
        case $type == 'high' && $scope == 'global':
            $rows = $this->highGlobalLeaderboards($user, $rank);
            break;
        case $type == 'high' && $scope == 'country':
            $rows = $this->highCountryLeaderboards($user, $rank);
            break;
        case $type == 'high' && $scope == 'region':
            $rows = $this->highRegionLeaderboards($user, $rank);
            break;
        default:
            return apiSend(null, 400);
    }

    foreach ($rows as $r) {
        $data[] = ['name' => $r->name, 'score' => (int) ($type == 'total' ? $r->total_score : $r->max_score), 'rank' => (int) $r->rank, 'is_user' => $user->id == $r->user_id];
    }

    return apiSend($data);
}

private function totalGlobalLeaderboards($user, $rank = 0)
{
    if (!$user) {
        return [];
    }

    $offset = $rank > 10 ? sprintf('OFFSET %d', $rank - 6) : '';
    $rowNumInit = $rank > 10 ? $rank - 6 : 0;
    return DB::select("SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, SUM(g.score) AS total_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC LIMIT 10 {$offset}) t, (SELECT @rownum := {$rowNumInit}) r");
}

private function totalCountryLeaderboards($user, $rank = 0)
{
    if (!$user) {
        return [];
    }

    $offset = $rank > 10 ? sprintf('OFFSET %d', $rank - 6) : '';
    $rowNumInit = $rank > 10 ? $rank - 6 : 0;
    $countryWhereClause = $user->country ? "WHERE g.country = '{$user->country}'" : 'WHERE g.country IS NULL';
    return DB::select("SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, SUM(g.score) AS total_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id {$countryWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC LIMIT 10 {$offset}) t, (SELECT @rownum := {$rowNumInit}) r");
}

private function totalRegionLeaderboards($user, $rank = 0)
{
    if (!$user) {
        return [];
    }

    $offset = $rank > 10 ? sprintf('OFFSET %d', $rank - 6) : '';
    $rowNumInit = $rank > 10 ? $rank - 6 : 0;
    $countryWhereClause = $user->country ? "WHERE g.country = '{$user->country}'" : 'WHERE g.country IS NULL';
    $regionWhereClause = $user->region ? "AND g.region = '{$user->region}'" : 'AND g.region IS NULL';
    return DB::select("SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, SUM(g.score) AS total_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id {$countryWhereClause} {$regionWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC LIMIT 10 {$offset}) t, (SELECT @rownum := {$rowNumInit}) r");
}

private function highGlobalLeaderboards($user, $rank = 0)
{
    if (!$user) {
        return [];
    }

    $offset = $rank > 10 ? sprintf('OFFSET %d', $rank - 6) : '';
    $rowNumInit = $rank > 10 ? $rank - 6 : 0;
    return DB::select("SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, MAX(g.score) AS max_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 10 {$offset}) t, (SELECT @rownum := {$rowNumInit}) r");
}

private function highCountryLeaderboards($user, $rank = 0)
{
    if (!$user) {
        return [];
    }

    $offset = $rank > 10 ? sprintf('OFFSET %d', $rank - 6) : '';
    $rowNumInit = $rank > 10 ? $rank - 6 : 0;
    $countryWhereClause = $user->country ? "WHERE g.country = '{$user->country}'" : 'WHERE g.country IS NULL';
    return DB::select("SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, MAX(g.score) AS max_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id {$countryWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 10 {$offset}) t, (SELECT @rownum := {$rowNumInit}) r");
}

private function highRegionLeaderboards($user, $rank = 0)
{
    if (!$user) {
        return [];
    }

    $offset = $rank > 10 ? sprintf('OFFSET %d', $rank - 6) : '';
    $rowNumInit = $rank > 10 ? $rank - 6 : 0;
    $countryWhereClause = $user->country ? "WHERE g.country = '{$user->country}'" : 'WHERE g.country IS NULL';
    $regionWhereClause = $user->region ? "AND g.region = '{$user->region}'" : 'AND g.region IS NULL';
    return DB::select("SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, MAX(g.score) AS max_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id {$countryWhereClause} {$regionWhereClause} GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 10 {$offset}) t, (SELECT @rownum := {$rowNumInit}) r");
}
```

As you can see, I'm not fluent in SQL.

Thank you.

---

**EDIT 2:** I don't know whether it is possible to combine leaderboards queries together or not, since each of them returns a result set of its own and not a single row, but if you think they can be combined, I'd be happy and grateful to learn that -- maybe return a multi-dimensional array.

There are 6 leaderboards: (total_score, max_score) x (global, country, region).

Each of these leaderboards contains a maximum of 10 records with this structure:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Mina", // Joined from users table.
        "user_id": 1,
        "toal_score": 7400, // Or max_score for Max Score Leaderboards.
        "rank": 1,
    },
    {...}
]
```

But I think it is possible to combine all of the (specific user's) ranks queries into one query because they return only one row, we can join multiple columns together. Something like this:

```
// SELECT ... WHERE user_id = 1;
{
    "total_score_global": 3540,
    "total_score_global_rank": 13,
    "total_score_country": 2830,
    "total_score_country_rank": 6,
    "total_score_region": 2600,
    "total_score_region_rank": 2,
    
    "max_score_global": 1084,
    "max_score_global_rank": 19,
    "max_score_country": 0, // No data for this user with given country.
    "max_score_country_rank": 0, // So his rank will be 0.
    "max_score_region": 950,
    "max_score_region_rank": 1,
}
```

All I want is to optimize the execution of these queries, possibly by reducing the query count --currently 12.

I've really tried to achieve this, but all I could get was empty result sets or syntax errors.

One of many of my tries was this:

```
SELECT
    r1.total_score AS total_score_global, r1.rank AS total_score_global_rank,
    r2.total_score AS total_score_country, r2.rank AS total_score_country_rank,
    r3.total_score AS total_score_region, r3.rank AS total_score_region_rank,
    r4.max_score AS max_score_global, r4.rank AS max_score_global_rank,
    r5.max_score AS max_score_country, r5.rank AS max_score_country_rank,
    r6.max_score AS max_score_region, r6.rank AS max_score_region_rank,
    FROM
        (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1) r1,
        (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'cname' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1) r2,
        (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'cname' AND region = 'rname' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1) r3,
        (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1) r4,
        (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'cname' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1) r5,
        (SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'cname' AND region = 'rname' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1) r6
```

Comment: which MySQL you using ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen MySQL version 5.7.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want,

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did that at the bottom of my question (Edit 2).

Comment: @ma3x - if you post the create of your table(s) with some sample date and expected result i will write you a query. you can put it on http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thank you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3f167/2

Comment: @BerndBuffen Did you see my SQL fiddle?

Comment: @ma3x - Yes I have. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what values ​​you want. Can you give me an example with 5-10 lines and the expected result, or the real result that comes out with your sample data. I am already adding an answer for the first 6 values ​​that you can test once . or you can phone me +49 2163 9879851

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thank you. Direct foreign calls are very expensive here, I've searched for your phone on Whatsapp and Telegram which I found you don't have accounts there. Do you have Skype or something which we can talk with an internet call?

Comment: i am out now for 2 hours. when i am back i will give you a whatsapp number

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added more details (Answer 2). can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT THE ANSWER

First you must add a index on the field **user_id**

**tmp sample**

```
SELECT
      SUM(sum_table.sum_score) AS total_score_global
    , SUM(IF( sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, 1,0)) AS total_score_global_rank

    , SUM(IF( sum_user.country = sum_table.country AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, sum_table.sum_score,0)) AS total_score_country
    , SUM(IF( sum_user.country = sum_table.country AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, 1,0)) AS total_score_country

    , SUM(IF( sum_user.region = sum_table.region AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, sum_table.sum_score,0)) AS total_score_region
    , SUM(IF( sum_user.region = sum_table.region AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, 1,0)) AS total_score_region_rank
    
    

FROM ( SELECT MAX(score) as sum_score, g.* FROM game_instances AS g GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY sum_score) AS sum_table
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(score) as sum_score, x.* FROM game_instances AS x WHERE user_id = 5  GROUP BY user_id) AS sum_user;
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use ranking;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [ranking]> 
MariaDB [ranking]> 
MariaDB [ranking]> SELECT
    ->       SUM(sum_table.sum_score) AS total_score_global
    ->     , SUM(IF( sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, 1,0)) AS total_score_global_rank
    -> 
    ->     , SUM(IF( sum_user.country = sum_table.country AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, sum_table.sum_score,0)) AS total_score_country
    ->     , SUM(IF( sum_user.country = sum_table.country AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, 1,0)) AS total_score_country
    -> 
    ->     , SUM(IF( sum_user.region = sum_table.region AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, sum_table.sum_score,0)) AS total_score_region
    ->     , SUM(IF( sum_user.region = sum_table.region AND sum_user.sum_score > sum_table.sum_score, 1,0)) AS total_score_region_rank
    ->     
    ->     
    -> 
    -> FROM ( SELECT MAX(score) as sum_score, g.* FROM game_instances AS g GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY sum_score) AS sum_table
    -> JOIN ( SELECT MAX(score) as sum_score, x.* FROM game_instances AS x WHERE user_id = 5  GROUP BY user_id) AS sum_user;
+--------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| total_score_global | total_score_global_rank | total_score_country | total_score_country | total_score_region | total_score_region_rank |
+--------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
|              33440 |                      12 |                9794 |                   9 |               2038 |                       2 |
+--------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [ranking]>
```

Comment: user_id field has a foreign key (on id in the users table) index.

Comment: We can take a look when my query is finish (EXPLAIN). on sqlfidle wars no index

Comment: This query returns error:
#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column '2048.x.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: i have add a sample in my query. i will change the query later

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how else I could explain what I want, so here I'll list all the queries that I've written along with their results.

I'm looking for a better approach to get these results, possibly by reducing the number of queries. currently, there are 12 queries which is too much.

1. Total Score Global Rank

In all rank queries:

- Return total_score/max_score: 0 and rank: 0 if no records present for the given user.
- Global, Country, and Region scores may differ since the user may set his country and region later or change them.

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1;

+---------+------+-------------+
| user_id | rank | total_score |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       1 |   16 |        1090 |
+---------+------+-------------+
```

2. Total Score Country Rank:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1;

+---------+------+-------------+
| user_id | rank | total_score |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       1 |   11 |        1090 |
+---------+------+-------------+
```

3. Total Score Region Rank:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.total_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.total_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS total_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' AND region = 'Qom' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.total_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1;

+---------+------+-------------+
| user_id | rank | total_score |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       1 |    3 |        1090 |
+---------+------+-------------+
```

4. Max Score Global Rank:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1;

+---------+------+-----------+
| user_id | rank | max_score |
+---------+------+-----------+
|       1 |   16 |       686 |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

5. Max Score Country Rank:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1;

+---------+------+-----------+
| user_id | rank | max_score |
+---------+------+-----------+
|       1 |   11 |       686 |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

6. Max Score Region Rank:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.rank, t1.max_score FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.max_score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM game_instances WHERE country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' AND region = 'Qom' GROUP BY user_id) p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY p.max_score DESC) t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 1;

+---------+------+-----------+
| user_id | rank | max_score |
+---------+------+-----------+
|       1 |    2 |       686 |
+---------+------+-----------+
```

7. Total Score Global Leaderboards:

In all leaderboards queries, we can update OFFSET and initial @rownum value to fetch the next page.

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, SUM(g.score) AS total_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;

+---------+---------+-------------+------+
| name    | user_id | total_score | rank |
+---------+---------+-------------+------+
| mina    |      17 |       11214 |    1 |
| sar     |      19 |        7058 |    2 |
| samaneh |      20 |        5448 |    3 |
| zahraa  |      18 |        5390 |    4 |
| reza    |       5 |        4402 |    5 |
| kazem   |      11 |        4350 |    6 |
| nazanin |       9 |        3428 |    7 |
| saina   |      12 |        2724 |    8 |
| sa      |      16 |        2568 |    9 |
| zeinab  |      14 |        2342 |   10 |
+---------+---------+-------------+------+
```

8. Total Score Country Leaderboards:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, SUM(g.score) AS total_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id WHERE g.country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;

+----------+---------+-------------+------+
| name     | user_id | total_score | rank |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+
| mina     |      17 |       11214 |    1 |
| sar      |      19 |        5680 |    2 |
| reza     |       5 |        4402 |    3 |
| kazem    |      11 |        4350 |    4 |
| saina    |      12 |        2724 |    5 |
| sa       |      16 |        2568 |    6 |
| hossein  |       6 |        1940 |    7 |
| Matrix   |       2 |        1670 |    8 |
| Player 3 |       3 |        1568 |    9 |
| zahra    |       8 |        1194 |   10 |
+----------+---------+-------------+------+
```

9. Total Score Region Leaderboards:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, SUM(g.score) AS total_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id WHERE g.country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' AND g.region = 'Qom' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY total_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;

+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+
| name                            | user_id | total_score | rank |
+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+
| sar                             |      19 |        5680 |    1 |
| Player 3                        |       3 |        1568 |    2 |
| MohamadSadegh Gh                |       1 |        1090 |    3 |
| Matrix                          |       2 |         280 |    4 |
+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+------+
```

10. Max Score Global Leaderboards:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, MAX(g.score) AS max_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;

+------------+---------+-----------+------+
| name       | user_id | max_score | rank |
+------------+---------+-----------+------+
| nazanin    |       9 |      3428 |    1 |
| zahraa     |      18 |      2666 |    2 |
| sar        |      19 |      2650 |    3 |
| mina       |      17 |      2380 |    4 |
| zeinab     |      14 |      2028 |    5 |
| reza       |       5 |      1746 |    6 |
| saina      |      12 |      1550 |    7 |
| ali rezvan |      15 |      1514 |    8 |
| sa         |      16 |      1480 |    9 |
| samaneh    |      20 |      1302 |   10 |
+------------+---------+-----------+------+
```

11. Max Score Country Leaderboards:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, MAX(g.score) AS max_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id WHERE g.country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;

+---------+---------+-----------+------+
| name    | user_id | max_score | rank |
+---------+---------+-----------+------+
| sar     |      19 |      2650 |    1 |
| mina    |      17 |      2380 |    2 |
| reza    |       5 |      1746 |    3 |
| saina   |      12 |      1550 |    4 |
| sa      |      16 |      1480 |    5 |
| hossein |       6 |      1288 |    6 |
| zahra   |       8 |      1194 |    7 |
| Matrix  |       2 |      1162 |    8 |
| kazem   |      11 |      1074 |    9 |
| nourf   |       7 |       750 |   10 |
+---------+---------+-----------+------+
```

12. Max Score Region Leaderboards:

```
SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank FROM (SELECT u.name, g.user_id, MAX(g.score) AS max_score FROM game_instances g INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = g.user_id WHERE g.country = 'Iran, Islamic Republic Of' AND g.region = 'Qom' GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max_score DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r;

+---------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+
| name                            | user_id | max_score | rank |
+---------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+
| sar                             |      19 |      2650 |    1 |
| MohamadSadegh Gh                |       1 |       686 |    2 |
| Player 3                        |       3 |       610 |    3 |
| Matrix                          |       2 |       280 |    4 |
+---------------------------------+---------+-----------+------+
```